# java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create when running MapReduce job

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm trying to run a simple MapReduce job to import data into HBase, but it cannot run, here's the error stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /user/SOME_PATH/hbase-staging (exists=false, cwd=file:/Users/SOME_PATH/2ND_PATH/HFileIntoHBase)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$RecordCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.writePartitions(HFileOutputFormat2.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configurePartitioner(HFileOutputFormat2.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat2.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat2.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(HFileOutputFormat2.java:367)
```

Here's my Java code:

```
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set(MAPRED_JOB_NAME, "steve_test");
        conf.set(HBASE_TABLE, "steve1");
        Job job = new Job(conf, conf.get(MAPRED_JOB_NAME));
        String output_table = conf.get(HBASE_TABLE);

        job.setJarByClass(PutUrlIntoHbase.class);
        job.setMapperClass(PutUrlIntoHbaseMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(PutSortReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);

        HTable table = new HTable(conf, output_table);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat2.class);
        HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table);

        if (job.waitForCompletion(true) && job.isSuccessful()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new PutUrlIntoHbase(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
```

As a few other similar posts suggested:
I've verified that I have permission to do `mkdir` in this directory.

My machine is Mac OS X: 10.11.6

Any help please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very old question at this point, but if somebody stumbles over it, you can set the temp dir manually to some existing directory like this:

`conf.set("hbase.fs.tmp.dir", "/some/other/staging/directory")`